# Getting Conversion error even though CTE should have only good dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, where-clause

Using SQL Server - my question is: how can I still be getting conversion errors though the CTE has only rows with good dates?

If I make a CTE with only rows that have valid dates... I am still getting the error.

```
WITH goodDates AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM impExpRaw2 
    WHERE ISDATE(dateofservice) = 1 
      AND DateofService <> '' 
      AND DateofService IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM goodDates 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, '7/31/2020', dateofservice) > 0
```

This yields the following error message which i would expect if there was a date like '2/31/2020' or 'cat' in that field...

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 293
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Kind of frustrating because I can not locate any rows w/ bad dates.

I can select into a temp table and then do dateDiff and things work fine.
To me, the fact that this works really rules out crazy data or fields w/ hidden chr(0) or something embedded in it.

```
select * 
into #gd 
from impExpRaw2 
where isdate(dateofservice) = 1   

select * 
from #gd 
where datediff (d, '7/31/2020', dateofservice) > 0
```

This is happening today on my dev machine, but it happens on newer versions as well

Version Info for those interested

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB3164398) - 13.0.1708.0 (X64)   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> HOW CAN I STILL BE GETTING THE CONVERSION ERROR GIVEN THE CTE HAS ONLY ROWS W GOOD DATES

Because SQL Server optimizes the *whole query*, and doesn't actually run the CTE subquery "first".  SQL Server is free to apply

```
DATEDIFF(d, '7/31/2020',dateofservice)
```

before applying either of

```
ISDATE(dateofservice)=1
```

and which it chooses depends on the execution plan.

Comment: that is a veryuseful piece of knowledge. ty.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend `try_cast()` rather than `isdate()`: it is much more reliable, since it actually tries to coerce the string to a date rather than relying on some complicated heuristic.

You could phrase the query as:

```
select *
from impExpRaw2
where try_cast(dateofservice as datetime) >= '20200801'
```

`try_cast()` returns `null` when the conversion fails, which does not satisfies the `where` predicate. Note that using this method, you don't need to explicitly filter out `null` or empty values (the conversion function will return `null` values well).

Finally: when declaring date literals, it is safer to use format `YYYYMMDD`, which SQL Server always recognizes as a date, regardless of the regional settings.